# How to switch from the .designer.cs file to the layout-designer in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#

Question is in title, is there a way, how i can switch from the .designer.cs file to the layout-designer or the .cs file in VS2015?

Comment: *.designer.cs is usually nested under a parent - and selecting the parent will bring you into the appropriate view.

Comment: I know, blub.designer.cs is under blub.cs. But how can i instantly switch from the blub.designer.cs to the layout-designer of blub.cs?

Comment: When you click on the node, it's the *designer* that comes up, not the auto-generated file. Just *don't* open the autogenerated file. The question isn't very clear

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to open the .designer.cs file in the first place. Just open the .aspx or .aspx.cs file. If you open the .aspx file, you can switch to design mode then, although good lord, why?!

Comment: I iam actualy searching a control in my whole project. So i have to find out, in which form the control is in use. But when i search after all references of the control then the studio just shows me all .designer.cs files

Comment: That is entirely normal.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > tick the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" checkbox.  Now it is easy.

Comment: that doesnt help me, it is already ticked.